# Are there recoverable read errors for a net.Conn?

Tags: go, networking

If the `.Read()` method of a [`net.Conn`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Conn) returns an error, does this imply that future reads also will fail with an error?  Or are there recoverable errors?  If so, how do I know whether/when to retry reads?

Comment: Future reads will fail, yes, but some actions can be re-tried safely. And in some cases, if you're using a higher-level library, such as `net/http`, certain actions will be automatically retried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you're not going to have any errors from a `conn.Read` operation that can be retried. Most uses of the `io.Reader` interface will assume that all errors are final.

Any `net` package errors that are assured to be retry-able will conform to the [`net.Error`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error) interface, and expose a `Temporary` method.

This is most often used in an `Accept` loop, like this paraphrased example from the http package

```
for {
    rw, e := l.Accept()
    if e != nil {
        if ne, ok := e.(net.Error); ok && ne.Temporary() {
            if tempDelay == 0 {
                tempDelay = 5 * time.Millisecond
            } else {
                tempDelay *= 2
            }
            if max := 1 * time.Second; tempDelay > max {
                tempDelay = max
            }
            time.Sleep(tempDelay)
            continue
        }
        return e
    }
}
```

Any other possible cases need to be handled on an individual basis, with knowledge of the protocol and situation at hand.

Comment: My question was about the `Read()` call, after a connection already has been accepted.  I assume I would use a similar retry-loop there?

Comment: @jochen: What "retry-able" error are you expecting? `net.Conn` isn't an implementation, but a `*TCPConn` for example would not have any error from reading that you could retry; except a timeout of course, but you would be checking for `Timeout` rather that `Temporary` in that case.

Comment: I get the `net.Conn` from a hijacked http connection, and I want to read a fixed (known) number of bytes from the connection.  I don't know what errors I have to deal with in my code for reading these bytes.  My question is basically "how to correctly read n bytes from the connection?"  I understand that short reads may happen, so I need a loop to gather the bytes.  But should my error handling look like the accept example above?  Or should I be giving up on the first error?  Or something else?

Comment: @jochen: No, you're not going to see any temporary errors reading from a tcp connection. Look at [`io.ReadFull`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadFull) which does what you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Timeout is the only recoverable error on read from a [net.TCPConn](https://godoc.org/net#TCPConn) and that error will only be returned when a [read deadline is set on the connection](https://godoc.org/net#Conn.SetReadDeadline).

Use  [Error.Temporary()](https://godoc.org/net#Error.Timeout) to check for errors that may resolve on retry and [Error.Timeout()](https://godoc.org/net#Error.Timeout) to check for timeouts:

```
 n, err := c.Read(buf)
 // process buf[:n] bytes
 if e.(net.Error); ok && e.Timeout() && e.Temporary() {
    // handle recoverable read deadline expiration
 } else if err != nil {
    // handle other errors
 }
```

Comment: That is incorrect. DNS errors can be temporary, like net/cgo_unix.go:func (eai addrinfoErrno) Temporary() bool { return eai == C.EAI_AGAIN }.

Comment: @PascaldeKloe The question asks about the `.Read()` method on a net.Conn.  None of the net.Conn implementations in the standard library use DNS on the `.Read()` method.

Comment: how do you know it's the only possible error that will be temporary?

Comment: @math2001 It's the only temporary read error mentioned in the documentation.  If the Go authors expected application programmers to retry reads in other scenarios, they would have called that out in the documentation.  Also, a grep of the source does not show other errors with with temporary set to true.

Answer (score 0):

See the specific error type of the net package https://golang.org/pkg/net/#OpError

It provides a specific `Temporary()` method to figure out if it is a non-terminal error.

To manually figure out which error is `Temporary` you have to go through each defined error within the net, os and some other internal packages.

To programmatically check for a temporary error, you might declare your own local `temporary interface{ Temporary() bool }`, or you can rely on this interface provided by the net package https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error

The `OpError.Temporary` method test if its internal error implements the `net.temporary` interface (https://golang.org/src/net/net.go?s=16056:16090#L501), and if so returns the  result of the call to `Temporary()` of the internal error, for example https://golang.org/src/net/net.go?s=19122:19157#L605.

I am unsure which read retry you are thinking about, however, internal fd.read methods implements retries for eagain
https://golang.org/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go#L165

Comment: While `OpError` has a `Temporary` method, it is not the only one and you should be looking for [`net.Error`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Error) (there is no public `net.Temporary` interface`)

Comment: indeed. forgot that. Is there any guarantee net errors implements that interface ? I can t find it in the doc. added some comments about your remark

Comment: There's no guarantee that all errors are a `net.Error`, but you are type asserting so it doesn't matter. If it's not a `net.Error`, it wasn't meant to be checked for `Temporary` and any further speculation requires precise knowledge about the situation.